# Use bukkit server with snapshot?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

I use Mojang's server for my single player games so that I can share them with other people and I thought I might as well switch to Bukkit since it can do more.

The only problem is... I am using the 12w26a snapshot and I already have a save file on my server which I want to move over to Bukkit.

I can handle transferring the maps but how can I make Bukkit work with 12w26a?

Comment: Your best bet is to try the latest [Development build](http://dl.bukkit.org/downloads/craftbukkit/list/dev/). Don't forget to back up your world!

Comment: the latest one seems to be "1.2.5 R4.1" does this correspond to the Minecraft version or should I just try anyway?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Bukkit does not update for snapshots. You cannot run a Bukkit server on anything except a primary release. Unfortunately, you are out of luck. You'll have to run a vanilla server or just wait for the next full version to be released.

Answer (score -5):

On the [Bukkit wiki homepage](http://wiki.bukkit.org/Main_Page) there's a link to download the development snapshot for both CraftBukkit and Bukkit.

Comment: -1 for being wrong. That's the latest developer snapshot *of craftbukkit* for the latest release version of Minecraft (1.3.2 at the moment), not a release of craftbukkit for the latest *Minecraft snapshot* (12w36a "pre-1.4"), which is what the question is looking for. @leaf68, you've probably discovered the error by now.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Yep, I was wondering why we couldn't log in with 12w37a took me a while to realize that was for 1.3.2